# Drawing texture using glDrawTexiOES in OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: opengl-es

First I am creating texture data using this code:

```
#define checkImageWidth 64
#define checkImageHeight 64

GLint checkImage[checkImageHeight][checkImageWidth][3];
void makeCheckImage(void)
{
    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 0; i < checkImageHeight; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < checkImageWidth; j++) {
            c = (((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8)==0))*255;
            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        }
    }
}
```

then i draw the texture using this code :

```
glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

// select our current texture
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, checkImageWidth, checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, checkImage);
glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, checkImageWidth, checkImageHeight);
```

But i do not see any output. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there some rest of the code? You need a glGenTexture, glBindTexture, glTexParametri... Then you need a call that glTexImage2D with width and height that are a power of 2, also try some glGetError() to see if there is an error somewhere...

Comment: yes..I have added that part

Comment: The width and height is of power of 2 and I am not getting any errors when i use glGetError().

Comment: What are your glViewprot coordinates?

Comment: i have used glViewport(0, 0, 320, 480)